# What is wrong with this method? (I need some awesome Ruby Coders)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, roles, restful-authentication

Ignoring rolerequirement with restfulauthentication method in a subdomain scope

I have created a site which utilizes subdomains and searches whether or not the user is at: `subdomain.domain.com` or `domain.com`. If the user is in `subdomain.domain.com, /views/layouts/application.html.erb` appears, if the user is in `domain.com /views/layouts/promo_site.html.erb` appears. To accomplish this I closely followed [Robby on Rails](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/01/11/subdomain-accounts-with-ruby-on-rails-explained) directions.

Both layouts utilize the same controller. In addition I use [rolerequirement](http://code.google.com/p/rolerequirement/) with restfulauthentication, for both of my views to function I've created methods which search your scope (url.com or subdomain.url.com)

I've isolated the following problem:

1. Method within the Controller is causing fail. "NoMethodError Controller: undefined method `require_role'"
2. If the controller is in the correct scope, url.com the `before_filter :check_if_role_is_required` method works fine. If it is in the subdomain.url.com scope, the `check_if_role_is_required` method produces a NoMethodError.

The following code is the `check_if_role_is_required method`:

```
def check_if_role_is_required 
require_role ["alt", "student worker"], :except => [:list, :show, :index, :create] unless promo_site?
end
```

*note the above code fails when `require_role ["alt", "student worker"], :except => [:list, :show, :index, :create]` is initiated, this code works fine outside of the check_if_role_is_required method, so this is probably a simple ruby error.

How can I rewrite this method to function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method itself looks ok.

Since you are getting the error when you are on subdomain.url.com, but not when you are on url.com, your problem isn't on the method definition, but on the code that handles "subdomain changing". That is the code you should check; it looks as if you are "not including" rolerequirement when you are on subdomain.url.com.

Comment: I fixed this removing  "before_filter" and simply called my method  :check_if_role_is_required